# Div does not support two images

Tags: html, css

I tried to make two separate div with different images attached to them. The problem is that when I put more than one div the second or the third image disappear and only the first in the CSS document appears.

HTML:

```
<div class="tokens">
  <div class="imageGriff", id="testphoto"></div>
  <div class="imageGriff" type="image" id="testphoto2"></div>
  <div class="imageSly", id="testphototwo"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imageSly {
  content: url("/t2.png");
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}​

.imageGriff{
   content: url("/token.png") no-repeat;
   position: relative;
   display: inline;
}​
```

[This is what I got when I have two divs with imageSly. With 2 of them 2 elements will appear but no imageGriff element.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNMcY.png)

Comment: There are no commas in an element. I.e `<div class="imageGriff", id="testphoto">` the `,` is wrong. A space is all you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't working due to syntax errors.

- Commas are not used to delimit HTML attributes
- The `content` css property does not expect to have `no-repeat` in it

```css
.imageSly {
  content: url("//placehold.it/200x100");
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.imageGriff {
  content: url("//placehold.it/300x150");
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="tokens">
  <div class="imageGriff" id="testphoto"></div>
  <div class="imageGriff" id="testphoto2"></div>
  <div class="imageSly" id="testphototwo"></div>
</div>
```